# How to pass html attributes to child <img> element using React and Typescript without "IntrinsicAttributes & HTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement> error"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a functional React component that wraps an image element:

```
type BlobImageProps = HTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement> & {
    blobId: string
}

function BlobImage(props: BlobImageProps){
    const {blobId, ...htmlAttributes} = props
    const [objectUrl, setObjectUrl] = useState<string>()
    // ...
    // ... load image blob using effect hook
    // ...
    return <img {...htmlAttributes} src={objectUrl}/>
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
function MyPage(){
    //...
    return (
        <BlobImage blobId="xyz1234" alt="Funny cats"/>
    )
}
```

However, I get a typeScript error saying

```
Type '{ blobId: string; alt: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement> & { blobId: string; }'.
  Property 'alt' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement> & { blobId: string; }'.
```

What's wrong with my typing? What type should `BlobImageProps` have?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking through the React types definitions,¹ it looks like you're looking for `ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>` rather than `HTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>`.

---

¹ How I did that: I pasted your type definition into my editor, put my cursor on `HTMLAttributes`, and asked it to show me the definition (<kbd>F12</kbd> in my case, VSCode). It took me to the `index.d.ts` for React (in `@types/react` in `node_modules`). I noted that that interface doesn't have `alt` (and doesn't use its type parameter for anything, which seems odd) so I searched for `alt` and found `ImgHTMLAttributes`.

Comment: Thank you. Is this documented anywhere on the React website? I couldn't find anything there. Is this such an unusal use case?

Comment: @Joerg - I haven't seen it documented. Doesn't mean it isn't. :-)